# WSO2-ESB500 / property mediator xpath json

Tags: wso2

Had a property mediator "customerData" inside my sequence who contains at least theses informations :

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2", 
  ...
}
```

See logs :

```
DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator} -  Setting property : customerData at scope : default to : 
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2":"value2",
    ...
} 
(i.e. result of expression : XX) {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator}
```

How to access fetch value of each key ?

I'm trying at first to log them but cannot parse these property as a valid json property.

Trying with thoses syntax :

- $ctx:customerData//key1/text()
- json-eval(customerData.key1)
- json-eval(get-property('customerData').key1)
- //key1/text()
- ...

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to reference a property inside a json evaluation.
What you can do is set the "customerData" property to the current message context using the payloadFactory mediator[1] and then use jsonpath to retrieve the data.

For example:

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>
    $1
    </format>
    <args>      
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:customerData")/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Afterwards you should be able to retrieve the data you are looking for:

`<property name="customerDataLine" expression="json-eval($.key1)"/>`

As a side note, if you don't want to lose the message that is currently in context you can save it to a property temporarily with the clone mediator and put it back into context as well. [2]

Another possible option would be to set the "type" of the property to "OM", then retrieving the data as xml with xpath directly might also work. Something like:

`<property name="customerDataLine" expression="$ctx:customerData/key1"/>`

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/PayloadFactory+Mediator

[2]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Clone+Mediator